# A playschool contains 4 boys and y girls.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On every Wednesday during winter, five students, of which at least three are boys, go to the zoological garden, a different group being sent every week. At the garden, each boy in a group is given a ball. If the total number of balls distributed is 368,then value of y is

1. 5
2. 6
3. 7
4. 8

I don't know the answer. It was in our exam. If anyone can help. Much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Why haven't you made any effort in even writing down this question properly, showing only the relevant information. For example, do we really care about "Wednesday", "winter", "zoological grden" (couldn't even copy-paste that correctly)? Feels like you're asking others to make an effort for you, while you're making non of that yourself.

Comment: To start:  You can have three boys and two girls or four boys and one girl.  How many different groups of each type can you make as a function of $y$?  Can you do that?

Comment: I didn't copy paste. I recalled it from a paper. That is all of the question. The entire question. I do apologize for the *grden*. I mistyped.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, I considered that. But do I consider both groups for each week untill 398 balls are completed? Also, isn't it possible that one week they could send 3 boys and then send 4 the next week? How do I include that?

Comment: it is not clear if all possible groups are being made? or just different groups, so then there must be at least 5,6,7 or 8 girls

Comment: In any case there must be about 100 visits total, so it's like 2 years of visiting, not really during a winter

Comment: Read the problem.  Each week one group is sent.  You need to compute the total number of different groups.  The balls distributed will be three times the number of groups with three boys plus four times the number of groups with three boys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that every possible group of students was sent to the garden, the question is solvable.

To start, there are two possible groupings, either 3 boys and 2 girls, or 4 boys and 1 girl.

With the former, the number of possible ways to choose this grouping is simply $_4$C$_3$ · $_y$C$_2$ which simplifies to $2y(y-1)$. With this grouping, three balls will be given to each group (because there are three boys in the group), so the total amount of balls received with this grouping is $6y(y-1)$.

Following the same logic with the latter grouping, we see that the total number of ways this grouping can be chosen is $_4$C$_4$ · $_y$C$_1$ which simplifies to just $y$. Thus, the total amount of balls received with this grouping is $4y$.

Now we have,

$$6y(y-1) + 4y = 368$$

Solving for $y$ yields $ y = $ -$\frac{23}{3}$ and $ y = 8$, from which the obvious answer is $y = 8$.